# Pulling a substring starting and ending with a special character from rows of a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `articles` with a column `body`.

Inside `body` column, I have a lot of rows having `<img>` tags, e.g

```
----------------------------------------
           body
----------------------------------------
This is <img src="www.abc.com/1"> artcle 1
This is article 2
This is <img src="www.abc.com/2"> article 3
This is article 4
```

Now I want to get all the `src` portions, like `www.abc.com/1`,`www.abc.com/2`,etc.

I got all such rows using

```
select body from articles where body like `%img%`
```

How can I extract only the link (src) portion?

Comment: you pull the full string into PHP, load the string into DOM, then use dom operations to extract it.

Comment: Use `SUBSTR` and `LOCATE` functions.

Comment: A bit optimized on Marc B answer is that you could limit the result on `WHERE body LIKE '%src=%'`. but yeah, don't try DOM parsing in MySQL, [unless you store a fully correctly formed XML document in there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html), which you clearly don't. (And even then it's hard to deal with multiple matches in one document).

Answer (score 1):

you can use substr method with locate and locate reverse to find the beginning double quote and the ending double quote from your src="www.abc.com/1" like so:

```
SELECT 
    body,
    SUBSTR(
        body, 
        LOCATE('"',body)+1, 
        (CHAR_LENGTH(body) - LOCATE('"',REVERSE(body)) - LOCATE('"',body))
    ) AS 'SRC URL'
FROM articles 
WHERE body LIKE '%img%'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3db0f/5)